# C++ Cx passing delegates to native c++

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I need to find a way to retrieve callbacks from C++/Cx back to native C++. In C++ code those are stored as function pointers, while in C++/Cx they are stored in delegates. I've found that in C# and C++/CLI there is a function like `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()` but seems like there is nothing even similar to this one in C++/CX. Is there really any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Someone who can give an answer might not know anything about C++/Cx. As your question is written right now, only an expert in C++/Cx and C++ could answer. If you could explain more about why you want to do this and what a delegate is, maybe a C++ expert can give a solution or a workaround. I know a some C++ but I have no idea what it is you are asking. I am not saying that your question is bad, but I don't understand it, since I don't know anything about delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++/Cx is the medium layer between C# app and C++ native library. And i managed to pass a pointer from C# to WinRt(C++/Cx) layer as follows:

```
del d = new del(callBackFunction);                  //declare a delegate and               
                                                    //add a function to delegate
IntPtr p = GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(d);        //retrieve pointer

w.retrieveCallbackFunction(p.toInt32());    //pass a pointer as int to WinRt layer
```

Inside WinRt layer inside retrieveCallbackFunction:

```
void* x=(void*)p;            //cast it to void*
callbackFunctionType ptr = (callbackFunctionType)x;   // cast it to a type
                                                      // of function pointer
ptr(...);            //call function
```

I know this isn't the prettiest solution but this one worked for me now.

**EDIT**

It also might be a good idea to prevent garbage collector from collecting function or delegate

```
GCHandle callbackHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(d); // !!!!
```

But now it is up to us to free this memory later.

Comment: I believe your second line should be: IntPtr p = GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(d);

Comment: `GCHandle` is for `.net`, not for `C++/CX` runtime. So your **EDIT** may not right.

Answer (score -1):

I have no clue about C++/CX but a quick search brought this up which for me sounds like what you are trying to accomplish:

[codeproject.com: Convert a Delegate to a Function pointer to Implement Callback function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3609/Convert-a-Delegate-to-a-Function-pointer-to-Implem)

Comment: Yeah sure, but this solution is about converting delegate to function pointer from C++/CLI to C++ so it unfortunately doesn't really help me.

Comment: So you are looking for the other way? C++ to C++/CLI?